# React routing using components (PageRenderer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm trying to do basic routing in React. Usually what I have done, and what I will mention later on, is use `element={<some page>}`. But currently I want to learn and experiment what other options there are, so I came across components where you insert a function. I have followed a tutorial and I did the exact same, except the tutorial uses an older version of router dom so it doesn't use Routes.

Here is the code:

App.js:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import Register from './pages/register';
import Login from './pages/login';
import PageRender from './PageRender';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <input type='checkbox' id='theme'/>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="main"> 
        <Routes> 
          <Route exact path="/:page" component={PageRender}/>
          <Route exact path="/:page/:id" component={PageRender}/>
        </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PageRender.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import NotFound from './components/NotFound'

const generatePage = (pageName) => {
    const component = () => require(`./pages/${pageName}`).default

    try {
        return React.createElement(component())
    } catch (err) {
        return <NotFound />
    }
}


const PageRender = () => {
    const {page, id} = useParams()
    let pageName = "";

    if(id){
        pageName = `${page}/[id]`
    }else{
        pageName = `${page}`
    }

    return generatePage(pageName)
}

export default PageRender
```

The login and register js are just basic arrow functions which display login or register (still didn't come to that part). What I want to do is when I enter the url, let's say for instance: http://localhost:3000/register, it sends me to register page and if I enter a wrong path it will send me to the "NotFound" page. But sadly, it doesn't work. I know I can work around this problem if I simply do this:

```
<Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
```

This method works, but currently I'm in the process of learning and I'm curious why this method didn't work.

Comment: Does the `App` code from the first snippet actually work? I suspect it wouldn't since the `react-router-dom` v6 `Route` components haven't a `component` prop. Even if you *were* still using RRDv5 you wouldn't want to use a function on the `component` prop, use the `render` prop instead. Do you have a more complete/accurate code example that actually runs?

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah the App works totaly fine with 0 errors in console. But doing this it doesent reroute I guess I will have to revert to old way with using elements. Here is the tutorial where he uses this and yeah it works for him: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwiXVvPcdk&t=1027s

Comment: The author of the youtube video appears to be using `react-router-dom` v5. In v6 the `Route` components don't take `component` or `exact` props and ***must*** be wrapped by a `Routes` component. If you had a working RRDv5 version of your code in a running codesandbox we could test more easily what needs to be changed to work with RRDv6.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah I was thinking that it was due to RRD version, well anywho thanks a lot for clearning that dilemma to me. cheers

Comment: @DrewReese Just tried the RRDv5 and yeah it works if you want you can post your answer here as well as how you can do similar solution to RRDv6 and I'll approve your answer. Once again cheers

Comment: I'll tinker around to see what I can get working in RRDv6 and try to write up a solution later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code working in `react-router-dom` v5, the trick was importing the components once in `App` so they are built/transpiled. The `PageRender` component worked as-is.

RRDv5

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import './pages/register';
import "./pages/login";
import PageRender from "./PageRender";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <input type="checkbox" id="theme" />
      <div className="App">
        <div className="main">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/:page/:id" component={PageRender} />
            <Route path="/:page" component={PageRender} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

RRDv6 - Swap the `Switch` component to the `Routes` component, and switch to using the `element` prop instead of the `component` prop to render the `PageRender` component as JSX.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import './pages/register';
import "./pages/login";
import PageRender from "./PageRender";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <input type="checkbox" id="theme" />
      <div className="App">
        <div className="main">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/:page/:id" element={<PageRender />} />
            <Route path="/:page" element={<PageRender />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-routing-using-components-pagerenderer]